# How to call ActiveSupport method inside rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, activesupport, rake-task

### This is what I'm trying:

```
require "active_support"

desc "test"
task :foo => [:environment] do
  parse(:categories) do |hash|
    # cleanup name
    hash[:name] = titlecase(hash[:name])
    # ...
  end
end
```

### This is the error I'm getting:

> undefined method `titlecase' main:Object

### I've also tried:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector::titlecase(hash[:name])
```

### Results in this error:

> undefined method `titlecase' ActiveSupport::Inflector:Module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
hash[:name] = hash[:name].titlecase
```

instead of what you are trying. it worked for me.